# Custom Navigation bar has one separated line

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I have added one custom `UINavigationBar` in my `UIViewController` with constraints top, trailing, leading = 0  and height = 64. In IOS 11, it showing one separator line between the `UINavigationBar`.

[image: Click here for ScreenShot]

Comment: Set `Top Space` to 22.

Comment: I need the same navigationBar color for status also @Buntylm.

Comment: better add one `UIView` as base view with height 66 give the same color and on top of that add the `UINavigationBar`

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

Comment: Hi, your answer removed the separator line but the navigation items and title are attached with status bar

Comment: what do you mean status bar ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set to navigation bar delegate and implement it in view controller

```
func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
     return .top
}
```